# useSleep hook in React

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

I'm building a kiosk display app with React, and after a certain amount of time with no mouse/touch/keyboard events happening, I would like my component to call some function, `goToSleep()`. Does anyone know of a `useSleep()` hook that looks something like this in use:

```js
const MyApp = (): JSX.Element => {
  const sleepConfig = {
    timer: 100000 //after 100000ms call the function
  }
  const setSleepMode = () =>{console.log("setting to sleep mode")}
  const sleepEvent = useSleep(setSleepMode(), sleepConfig)

  return <div {...sleepEvent}>BODY</div>
};
```

Comment: 1: you are missing an `=` between `sleepConfig` and `{...`, 2) you are calling the function `setSleepMode` immidiately instead of passing the function itself to `useSleep` and 3) what are even wanting `sleepEvent` to look like if it has `div` props?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-use has a [`useIdle`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useIdle.md) hook that achieves this:

```
import {useIdle} from 'react-use';

const Demo = () => {
  const isIdle = useIdle(3e3);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>User is idle: {isIdle ? 'Yes ' : 'Nope'}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```